# Win 2003 Terminal Server Keeps Crashing

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, terminal-server, printing

Welcome to my morning emergency:

System is Windows 2003 SP2, operating as a terminal server. There are several printers shared from this system, and users connecting also map their locally mapped printers in their TS session. Intermittently, and sometime frequently, the print spooler service stops:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   Application Error
Event Category: (100)
Event ID:   1000
Date:       2/24/2011
Time:       8:16:47 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   
Description:
Faulting application spoolsv.exe, version 5.2.3790.4759, faulting module msvcrt.dll, version 7.0.3790.3959, fault address 0x00038efa.
```

I can re-start the service, and things work "normally" until it crashes again.

I have a hunch that it's *one* printer and/or one *user* causing the problem, and I've asked for detailed information from user-space to help isolate it. Is there anything else I can do to try and isolate the problem, or do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your initial reaction is probably right. I would start by uninstalling that printer used by the user, and reinstalling with the latest software. Try updating or installing .Net Framework 2.0 as I believe C++ can be a culprit, if you have some custom apps. 
Also, it's usually default, but check that your spooler service is set to restart on failure.

Comment: Ahh, but the problem is I don't know *which* user or printer it is. I'm trying to figure out which one to look at...

Comment: oh i see, so there are no other Events related to these problems, as far as user or profile fails?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Citrix StressPrinters utility (doesn't need to be a Citrix server): http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX109374.

Run it, and it will ask which drivers you want to test. It then installs a dummy printer with each of the selected drivers, and reports back any errors. If the server crashes on installing one of the drivers, you'll know that one is likely causing the problem. If it doesn't crash, but does report errors installing it, I'd recommend removing it temporarily and see if that fixes the crashing.